# Порядок элементов в PriorityQueue

Tags: java, коллекции, очередь, итераторы

Создается `PriorityQueue` из элементов `Integer` с использованием компаратора

```java
IntComparator intComparator = new IntComparator();
PriorityQueue<Integer> integerPriorityQueue2 = new PriorityQueue<>(intComparator);

integerPriorityQueue2.add(4);
integerPriorityQueue2.add(3);
integerPriorityQueue2.add(5);
integerPriorityQueue2.add(9);
integerPriorityQueue2.offer(1);
```

Компаратор:

```java
@Override
public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
    return (o1 - o2);
}
```

Проходим по полученной коллекции итератором:

```java
System.out.print("IntegerPriorityQueue2. Using an iterator: ");
Iterator<Integer> iterator2 = integerPriorityQueue2.iterator();
while(iterator2.hasNext()) {
    System.out.print(iterator2.next() + ", ");
}
System.out.println("");
```

Ожидание:

```
1, 3, 4, 5, 9
```

Реальность:

```
1, 3, 5, 9, 4
```

В чем причина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно вывести содержимое приоритетной очереди в желаемом порядке, вместо итератора следует воспользоваться циклом, в котором элементы вычитываются при помощи метода `poll`:

```java
while (!integerPriorityQueue2.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.print(integerPriorityQueue2.poll() + "  ");
}
```

Вывод:

```
1  3  4  5  9
```

Для гарантированной сортировки следует либо воспользоваться реализацией `SortedSet` типа `TreeSet`, или же содержимое очереди придётся сортировать отдельно, например, как указано в документации: *If you need ordered traversal, consider using Arrays.sort(pq.toArray()).* или при помощи стрима:

```java
integerPriorityQueue2.stream().sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

Также следует заметить, что данная реализация `IntComparator` не отличается по сути от обычной сортировки целых чисел в порядке возрастания, которая и так применяется в приоритетной очереди по умолчанию.

К тому же данная реализация содержит потенциальное целочисленное переполнение, т.е. по сути некорректна, и данный класс лучше было бы заменить на ссылку на метод `Integer::compare`:

```java
PriorityQueue<Integer> integerPriorityQueueAsc = new PriorityQueue<>(Integer::compare); // по возрастанию
```

или обратным компаратором `Comparator.reverseOrder()` для сортировки по убыванию:

```java
PriorityQueue<Integer> integerPriorityQueueDesc = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.reverseOrder()); // по убыванию
```

Answer (score 0):

Приоритетная очередь не упорядоченная коллекция. Если вам повезёт - в большинстве реализаций минимум будет на первом элементе.

[PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using Arrays.sort(pq.toArray()).

Статья [Двоичная куча](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0) объясняет как устроена в большинстве случаев приоритетная очередь. Здесь описана очередь максимумов, а очередь в Java - очередь минимумов. В остальном описание верное.